# If checkbox is already checked on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Using this jquery, i'm looping through elements and checking whether the relevant checkbox is checked.

When the page loads, the checkboxes are checked, but the console is showing `console.log( id + ' not checked' );`

Have I missed something, because as far as I can see it should be showing `console.log( id + ' checked' );` in the console

Code and HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.row').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log($(element).attr("id"));
    default_status($(element).attr("id"));
  });
});

function default_status(id) {
  if ($('#dr_default_' + id).is(':checked')) {
    console.log(id + ' checked');
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).val('');
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).attr('placeholder', 'default');
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).attr('disabled', true);
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).removeClass('required');
    }
  } else {
    console.log(id + ' not checked');
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).val('');
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).attr('placeholder', '');
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).attr('disabled', false);
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).addClass('required');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="dr_default_1" class="row" onclick="default_status('1');" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number1_1" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number2_1" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number3_1" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>
      <select name="" id="dr_dialing_1" class="form-control">

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="dr_default_2" class="row" onclick="default_status('2');" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number1_2" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number2_2" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number3_2" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>
      <select name="" id="dr_dialing_2" class="form-control">

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it probably ought to, yes. Can you show an example of the related HTML? Show us a few of your rows. Maybe there's some other subtle error causing your problem.

Comment: BTW as a secondary point...as per the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) you should be using .prop() instead of .attr() to set "disabled" - because it's technically a property and not a plain attribute. The page says _"To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method"_

Comment: @ADyson see update

Comment: In your default_status function, just refer to id, not '#dr_default_' + id. ID should containt #dr_default_1, for example

Comment: You should consider using a different way of selecting elements, perhaps with a meaningful `data-` attribute. It would make reading the code much easier.

Comment: Side notes; `id` is a property on an Element, so `$(element).attr("id")` is invoking two methods unnecessarily.  Just use `element.id`.  Secondly, `.is(':checked')` uses a pseudoselector to determine the boolean value, however `.prop('checked')` on an already found element returns the exact same thing, with a direct property retrieval, and not attempting to process the pseudoselector.  Win win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the ID you pass into the "default_status()" function is already complete apart from the `#` to make it into a valid CSS/jQuery selector.

This means that when you run `$('#dr_default_' + id)` it actually makes the final selector `$('#dr_default_dr_default_1')` (for example), and of course jQuery cannot find that, so it reports it as not checked.

Just remove the hard-coded id part from your test and it'll work:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.row').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log($(element).attr("id"));
    default_status($(element).attr("id"));
  });
});

function default_status(id) {
  if ($('#' + id).is(':checked')) {
    console.log(id + ' checked');
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).val('');
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).attr('placeholder', 'default');
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).prop('disabled', true);
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).removeClass('required');
    }
  } else {
    console.log(id + ' not checked');
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).val('');
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).attr('placeholder', '');
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).prop('disabled', false);
      $('#dr_number' + i + '_' + id).addClass('required');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="dr_default_1" class="row" onclick="default_status('1');" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number1_1" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number2_1" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number3_1" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>
      <select name="" id="dr_dialing_1" class="form-control">

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="dr_default_2" class="row" onclick="default_status('2');" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number1_2" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number2_2" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="" id="dr_number3_2" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>
      <select name="" id="dr_dialing_2" class="form-control">

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```